# Get the last created entry in a database

Tags: c#, mysql

What I am trying to do is retrieve the index of the last inserted entry into a table.

For example, when I enter a new row into a table, like so:

```
INSERT INTO _tablename(_col2, _col3, _col4) VALUES ('abc', 123, 'def');
```

How can I get the index, or the primary key of the row? If I use a generic select query, in this particular table there a chance of multiple returns. I.e:

```
SELECT * FROM _tablename WHERE _col2 = 'abc', _col3 = '123', col4 = 'def'
```

could return:

```
_tablename
+------------------------------+
| ID  | _col2  | _col3 | _col4 |
+------------------------------+
| 1   | abc    | 123   | def   |
| 23  | abc    | 123   | def   |
| 34  | abc    | 123   | def   |
| etc......
```

How can I get the index (or `ID`) of the last inserted row?

NOTE: I do know about `last_insert_id()`, but the last time I tried that in a query, it was returning multiple values, none of which matched up with the last inserted row `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

If ID is an identity, and you are fine with running a select, this would work:

```
select top 1 [ID] from _tablename order by [ID] desc
```

Which selects the first record from the result set, ordered by the ID column in descending order.  In other words, always select only the last insert made to the table.